# Custom NSError weird behaviour Swift

Tags: swift, nserror

In Swift, I have a custom NSError, I need to get the error userInfo dictionary and add things later, but it is nil in the assign line, but then `error.userInfo` have an object...

With error.userInfo as nil:

```
class MyError: NSError {

    init(error: NSError) { 
      var newUserInfo = error.userInfo

      ...newUserInfo is nil...
      super.init(...)
    }

}
```

If I assign it 2 times it works ( I know there's something missing but what?)

```
init(error: NSError) { 
  var newUserInfo = error.userInfo
  newUserInfo = error.userInfo

  ...newUserInfo now contains a dictionary...
}
```

Why?

Comment: is `newUserInfo` an instance variable, or only a local variable? Are you possibly declaring it twice?

Comment: It is a local variable and I'm declaring it only there

Comment: Just tried it and had no problems assigning it, can you post the rest of the code.

Comment: How do you know it's nil? Your code doesn't do anything to test or log the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks *maybe* compiler bug-ey to me, but it's hard to tell without seeing more of your code. At any rate, this sort of thing is easier to debug if you use conditional cast. `userInfo` in swift is a `Dictionary<NSObject: AnyObject>?`; if you're getting this from a Cocoa API you can do something like:

```
if let userInfo = error.userInfo as? [NSObject: NSObject] {
    // modify and assign values as necessary
}
```

this will at least make it clearer where things are breaking.

Comment: the only possible problem with that approach is that you might end up with an empty dictionary in a place where it would be more useful to understand that userInfo was nil.